# Why can't I access elements of a 2D array if I have declared it using pointer notation?

Tags: c, pointers

Below are two 2D arrays - one of which is declared using array notation and the other using pointer notation,(i.e), pointer to a group of contiguous 1D arrays (not array of pointers).

```
int array1[][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
int (*array2)[3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

I am able to access the elements of array1 using both array and pointer notation.

```
 //accessing the 3rd element of the first row (of array1)
printf("array1[0][2]=%d",array1[0][2]);//3
printf("\n*(*array1+2)=%d",*(*array1+2));//3
```

However, when I try to access the same for array2, it generates a run-time error.

```
//accessing the 3rd element of the first row (of array2)    
printf("\n*(*array2+2)=%d",*(*array2+2));
printf("\narray2[0][2]=%d",array2[0][2]);
```

Is there something wrong in the way I have declared these arrays? I have also tried declaring array2 as static, but it still generates the error.

Why does this error occur when declared using pointer notation?  How do I correct it?

There is no error however, if the last 2 lines are replaced as follows:

```
printf("\n(*array2+2)=%d",(*array2+2));//9
printf("\narray2[2]=%d",array2[2]);//25
```

But what does this mean? If I give `array2[3]`, then the value increases by 4 (the size of int)

Comment: What compiler warnings are you getting from `int (*array2)[3] = {...}`?

Comment: You should be getting a *lot* of warnings if you've turned on warnings. That's not a valid initialization.

Comment: Tip: `*(x + n)` is almost always better expressed as `x[n]`. This goes doubly for `x[n][m][o]` where the alternative is a jumbled mess of brackets and junk that no human will understand.

Comment: An array is not a pointer. You cannot declare an array using pointer notation. You declare an array using array notation, and a pointer using pointer notation.

Comment: @tadman Oh, yes...You're right. 9 warnings

Comment: Now we're talking. That should highlight the issue in more specific terms. `clang` is great at pointing out what's wrong in understandable terms, though GCC will grumble a lot in a more incoherent fashion that will still indicate something's not right.

Comment: @user3386109 Braces around scalar initializer; initialization makes pointer from integer w/o a cast; excess elements in scalar initializer

Comment: Yes, the translation of those warnings is that the compiler converted the number `1` to an address, and stored it in the pointer. It then ignored the rest of the line. As a result, the pointer `array2` is pointing to an invalid address.

Comment: Save your time, use `-Werror`.

Answer (score 4):

This code is illegal, because the initializer for a scalar must be a single expression (optionally enclosed in braces):

```
int (*array2)[3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

You should get a compiler diagnostic message. If you don't then please adjust your compiler settings.

The behaviour you get from any generated executable is meaningless since this is not a correct C program, so the rest of the question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

in C u cannot generate an array using such a method.

to generate an array at fix size u have to int array[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};

with that u can point a pointer to it and access it however you want;

void* p = (void*)array;

printf("%i",*((int*)p + 3)); //4